# AnticaptchaException: [ERROR_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST:1]Account authorization key not found in the system

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, recaptcha

I'm trying to use 2captcha for bypassing captcha while scraping a category of products at wayfair.com
The code I'm using is;

```
def parse(self,response):
    l=[]
    resp3 = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
    self.driver.get("https://www.wayfair.com/filters/storage-organization/sb6/closet-systems-c1833181-a72947~471760-a72947~471761-a72947~471762-a72947~471763-a72947~493985-a72947~494649.html")
    our_condition = resp3.xpath('//span[@class="BrowseHeaderWithSort-roadsign"]/text()').get()
    # if resp3.xpath('//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]').get() != None:
    if our_condition in ['Closet Systems']:
        print('/////30 sec/////')
        time.sleep(2)
        
    else:
        print('captcha detected')
        time.sleep(60)
        while True:
            api_key = '4f4796f8w4782b0d45621897818c7d58e'
            site_key = '6LfaBQEaAAAAAG8Z0xFqTFgOykhR3HmCEPlImW2T'  # grab from site
            client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
            task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(self.driver.current_url, site_key)
            while True:
                job = client.createTask(task)
                print("Waiting for solution")
                job.join()
                response = job.get_solution_response()
                print("captcha solution", response)
                if len(response) > 0:
                    break
            print('injecting the token on html')
            self.driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="{response}";')
            print('injecting the token on html. Success!')
            time.sleep(3)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="submit"]').click()
            time.sleep(3)
            resp = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            if resp.xpath('//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]/@data-site-key').get() == None:
                break
```

the error I'm getting in VS code is here

```
raise AnticaptchaException( python_anticaptcha.exceptions.AnticaptchaException: [ERROR_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST:1]Account authorization key not found in the system 2021-03-02 19:10:09 [scrapy.extensions.logstats]
```

I'm struggling to know what is the actual problem, how to get away with it, and let the 2captcha solve the captchas while scraping. Thanks

Comment: Well, the actual problem is wayfair.com doesn't want you to scrape their site.  They have code to defend against exactly this kind of code.  The `api_key` and `site_key` are probably dynamic, so you can't just reuse them.

Comment: Does it mean, I should leave scraping wayfair.com, Or is there any way out, which could still help me scrape the data

Comment: I'm sure it is POSSIBLE, but you might need their help to figure out the key mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm if you have selected `developer` mode.
[image]